# Emulate landscape iPad orientation in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Following code runs iPad emulation in Chrome in `portrait` orientation.
How can I change it to get `landscape` orientation?

```
const {Builder, By, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var driver = new Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options()
    .setMobileEmulation({deviceName: 'Apple iPad'})
    .addArguments('start-maximized')
  ).build();
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651828/178988)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Emulation on Chrome Driver doesn't support multiple things. one of them is changing the orientation before starting Chrome or on the Fly. That is why it is recommended not to fully rely on Emulators.

Please check "Differences between mobile emulation and real devices" section in http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation

> Testing a mobile website on a desktop using mobile emulation can be
>   useful, but testers should be aware that there are many subtle
>   differences such as:  entirely different GPU, which may lead to big
>   performance changes; mobile UI is not emulated (in particular, the
>   hiding url bar affects page height); disambiguation popup (where you
>   select one of a few touch targets) is not supported; many hardware
>   APIs (for example, orientationchange event) are unavailable.